# Passing Dynamic Arrays to functions in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I am trying to pass a dynamic array to a function in Solidity:

```
function process(string[] data) public {
  // process data
}
```

I would like to call the function as:

```
process(['data1','data2','data3']);
```

Solidity doesn't like that, the only way I have found is:

```
contract fooContract {
  string[] data = ['data1','data2','data3'];

  function test() public {
    process(data);
  }
  function process(string[] data) public {
    // process data
  }
}
```